# How to TypeScript a multiple request \ response types function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have multiple types of requests:

```js
   interface RequestA {};
   interface RequestB {};
```

Each request has a corresponding response type that will be returned:

```js
   interface ResponseA {};
   interface ResponseB {};
```

I need other modules in my application to be able to **add additional request and response types** (Using `typescript declaration merging` maybe?), so someone else can register `RequestC` and its corresponding type `ResponseC`.

Eventually I want to have a typed `executeRequest` function that takes a typed request object, and the returned response to have the correct type.

```js
   const request: RequestA;
   const response = myHandler.executeRequest(request);
   // type of response should be ResponseA

   // This type is registered by some other module!
   const anotherRequest: RequestC;
   const anotherResponse = myHandler.executeRequest(anotherRequest);
   // type of response should be ResponseC
```

How would you recommend to type this function `function executeRequest(request: ?) => ?` with TypeScript?

Comment: Have you considered [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)?

Comment: I don't think it would work with being able to add additional request and response types